# Rails, Active Record unknown attribute error with _id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have an ActiveRecord Model class `Sample` with a field named `prev_sample_id` which doesn't hold a reference to an AR association. This field also has the uniqueness constraint. Now I get an error from *ActiveRecord Unknown attribute `prev_sample_id=`* on the prev_sample_id field while running RSpec tests. My model class is given below : -

```
class Sample < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :prev_sample_id, uniqueness: true
end
```

*schema.rb : -*

```
create_table "samples", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "text"
    t.integer  "prev_sample_id", null: false
end
```

So how can I have a field in an AR model class with the suffix `_id` but which doesn't refer to a relation and doesn't throw the *unknown attribute error*.

Comment: If you are only getting the error in RSpec try running `bin/rake db:test:load` which loads the schema for the test database from `schema.rb`. It sometimes seems to get stuck so new migrations are not run against the test db.

Comment: ActiveRecord does not care if your column name ends with `_id`. The naming is  just a Rails convention. But I don't really see why you should not use a self-referencing association here though. So the issue is either that the migration is not performed on the DB or a typo somewhere.

Comment: @max - i agree with u here, but doesn't the fact its mentioned in the schema.rb, proof enuf, its been migrated properly ?

Comment: The schema.rb is only really a snapshot showing what the database schema should look like. It does not guarantee that the actual database matches.